# OAuth 2.0 for distributable web applications

Tags: oauth, google-api

I'm trying to figure out, how to use OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs from my web app. The problem is, that the protocol require developer to register **redirect_uri** (URL of page receiving access token). But my application can be distributed to many customers and can be hosted on endless number of servers. There is no way to know **redirect_uri** beforehand.

Google offers another option for installed applications, but I cannot use this variant neither. Auth server returns access code in window title and this information cannot be accessed from JavaScript of our page (JS cannot access content of window opened using `window.open();` if that content comes from different server).

To conclude:

1. Cannot use method for web applications, because I don't know all URLs where will our app run in the future.
2. Cannot use method for installed applications, because window title is not accessible from our JavaScript code.

Is there any recommendation, how to use Google's OAuth 2.0 from **distributable** web application running on a lots of servers?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you cannot access the window title? If your app is opening the window, it should be able to access it. It should be possible to do this in a similar way you would do it in a mobile app.

If all attempts fail, you could set up a proxy server (that has a known redirect URI) and hands out the Google tokens to all your clients. Or better each of the apps could have its own proxy server - the server it was downloaded from. But then if each OAuth client can only have one redirect URI, each app would have to be a separate OAuth client.